# Permission denied when importing matplotlib.pyplot using python

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, spyder

I get this trackback when importing `matplotlib`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
/Users/ny/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:273: UserWarning: Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.
  warnings.warn('Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-18-eff513f636fd>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  File "/Users/ny/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 29, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar

  File "/Users/ny/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 34, in <module>
    import matplotlib.collections as collections

  File "/Users/ny/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 27, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases

  File "/Users/ny/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 62, in <module>
    import matplotlib.textpath as textpath

  File "/Users/ny/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 15, in <module>
    import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager

  File "/Users/ny/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1421, in <module>
    _rebuild()

  File "/Users/ny/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1406, in _rebuild
    fontManager = FontManager()

  File "/Users/ny/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1059, in __init__
    self.ttflist = createFontList(self.ttffiles)

  File "/Users/ny/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 581, in createFontList
    font = ft2font.FT2Font(fpath)

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Fonts/WarnockPro-Subh.otf'
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: This would be easier to read if you highlighted all of the traceback and then selected the brackets, which would format it better. I tried to edit it but I'm getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the user executing the process does not have access to the file `/Library/Fonts/WarnockPro-Subh.otf` or one of it's parent directories.

Have you tried to `chown` the file or directory?

```
chown user_name file
chown user_name folder
chown -R user_name folder #recursive
```

Comment: Im still new to python, but i tried to chown it and i got Errno 1 operation not permitted

Comment: Do it as a user with sudo privileges.